# How to omit some values in an array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a vector **vec**-it's length is 1774. And I need to make a vector **n** of length 10 which will contain 10 numbers of **vec** with similar step like:

```
n=[0, 178, 356, 534, 712, 890, 1068, 1246, 1424, 1602]
```

First and last numbers do not have to be same as in **vec**. My try:

```
# -*- coding: cp1250 -*-
from __future__ import division

newLength=10
vec=range(1774)

step=round(len(vec)/newLength);

n=range(0,len(vec),int(step))

print n
print len(n)
```

But it results into the vector of length 11. When I set newLength=22 then I get exactly 22. So it is problem of rounding (I also tried math.ceil and math.floor-it works for newLength=10 but not for newLength=554). Is there any other way how to get vector **n**?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873626/choose-m-evenly-spaced-elements-from-a-sequence-of-length-n)?

Comment: I tried it, but the result was:

<generator object takespread at 0x7f802317af00>

and not any array. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You can turn a `generator` into a `list` using `list(generator)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about this:

1. You have 1774 apples.
2. You want to split the apples into 554 equally sized groups.
3. The group size must be 1774/554 = 3.261.
4. You round the group size down and get 3.
5. You get 1774//3 = 591 groups.
6. You see this is wrong.
7. You decide to round up instead and get 4.
8. You get 1774//4 = 443 groups.
9. You see this is wrong as well.
10. You realise that you must be able to have .261 of an apple.
11. You write code to facilitate this.
12. You decide to have a party because you now have 1774//3.261 = 544 groups!

The code:

```
new_length = 554
vector = # some list
step = len(vector)/new_length
n = (i*step for i in range(new_length))
new_vector = [vector[int(round(i))] for i in n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the solution. Thx to the  jonrsharpe

```
from math import ceil

def takespread(sequence, num):
    length = float(len(sequence))
    for i in range(num):
        yield sequence[int(ceil(i * length / num))]

if __name__=="__main__":
    newLength=55
    vec=range(1774)

    print len(list(takespread(vec, newLength)))
```